# Alarm with out using UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, nstimer, uilocalnotification, alarm, background-foreground

Is there any way to develop a iphone application without using local notifications. The application should trigger alarm even in Lock state, so that I can make network call on lock state.
It may use local notification in background state.

Answer (score 1):

No, even if you manage to get you app to run in the background, by miss use of the supported background mades, you can only alert the user with a `UILocalNotification`.

Comment: Yes, I will have to alert the user through UILocalNotification when in background mode. But I need some other approach to trigger the alarm when in foreground and the screen is locked.

Comment: You can't do anything on the lockscreen, you will have to use zUILocalNotification` for this as well.

Comment: I tried it with UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend set as YES. The timer is running and alarm is triggering. But for some reason it does't trigger :(

Comment: When you set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` you will be closed and does not suppended. Also when the lockscreen is displayed since iOS 5 apps are background. And when an app is backgrounded all `NSTimers` are stoped and will not fire. Like I said you will need to use `UILocalNotification`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to trigger alarm using dispatch_walltime even when the app goes to sleep mode.
Previously I was using NSTimer and dispatch_time, which will stop working when the app goes to sleep mode.
[Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)